# VSCode TypeScript lint

Tags: javascript, typescript, lint, visual-studio-code, tslint

People, who develop TypeScript used Visual Studio Code? I'm trying to use it too. But I have no validation(ts-lint) warnings or errors. I just got such messages on build:

```
ts-lint start
src/constants/type.ts[22, 2]: file should end with a newline
src/constants/type.ts[6, 5]: misplaced opening brace
ts-lint end
```

Example:

`1 == 2`

Such expression in JS file will message me that it will be better to use `1 === 2`.
But this expression in TS file will work and not even show any warning.

What can I do to enable such validation in TypeScript, while typing?

Comment: I work on vs code with typescript and errors are shown up while I'm typing, sometimes I must save the file in order to get errors. I get errors at build time too. Can you give us a part of code which you should get error-message and vs code is not doing that?

Comment: I get syntax and intellisence errors too. But i do not get lint(code style) warnings. I wrote the example, when Js message me to write a === b instead of a == b. But Ts in VSCode have no warnings on such expression.

Comment: TSLint has a rule that enforces usage of `==` instead of `===` called `triple-equals`. Maybe it's not enabled?

Comment: I'm not seeing my TypeScript errors as errors inside of VSCode either. I'm curious if having ESLint installed or having a jsconfig.json file is related to this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Just had the exact same problem and seem to have resolved by adding "typescript" to the eslint.validate array in workspace settings

```
{
 "eslint.validate": [
    "javascript",
    "javascriptreact",
    "typescript"
    ]
}
```

Should you be new to VSCode. F1 => type "settings" => from the dropdown select either "user settings" (any project for that logged in user) or "workspace settings" (that one project only) => paste the above object on the right pane (or extend the existing object should there be one)

Comment: that said, at hindsight, the correct thing to do is to install the [ts-lint plugin](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-tslint)

Answer (score 0):

Please update to 0.8.0 version of vs code, just released. JavaScript Linting as you Type is now supported. https://code.visualstudio.com/updates

Comment: Does that include TypeScript linting with tslint?

Comment: No, it isn't. JavaScript linting works great without ESLint(JSHint), just setup few settings in VSCode workspace. But i can't find how to enable TypeScript linting.

Comment: Yes this is only for javascript. Why you need ts-lint ? Typescript is so nice 'language' you can not make these kind of errors with ease :P

Answer (score 0):

I did some experimentation running into a similar problem and found that I had a `jsconfig.json` file laying around that was created prior to converting code over to TypeScript. After removing/renaming that file and restarting VSCode it appears that my TypeScript compiler errors are now showing up as the error output when doing a build in VSCode as opposed to seemingly unrelated errors about unresolved imports.

I'm not sure if this is the same problem you're experiencing but hopefully it's of some help to you or somebody else.